# NSDateFormatter in cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdateformatter

I'm working on an application for mac (cocoa application).
I'm formatting date for any specific timezone using NSDateFormatter.
Its working fine when I run the application using xcode, but when I run .app file directly without using xcode.

The date is not formatting accordingly.

The code which I'm using is:

```
 - (NSDate *)parseDateString: (NSString *)dateString withFormat: (NSString *)format {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *result = nil;

    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat: format];

    result = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateString];
#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
    [dateFormatter release];
#endif
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What string are you feeding it? What result are you expecting? What result are you getting?

Comment: Hi, for dateString: 4/01/2013 5:30 PM +0000 we are expecting result as: 4/01/2013 17:30 +0000. When I'm running the source code within xcode, it is working as expected. But when I run the .app file , getting the result: 4/01/2013 12:00 +0000, seems the code is unable to execute my time zone.

Comment: My time zone is GMT+5:30

Comment: I'm using XMLRPC.framework and the code slot is included in this framework.

Comment: How are you inspecting the date? And are you intending to parse a date that is on April 1st, or January 4th? (The former is what that string means in that locale.)

Comment: Its January 4th? Thanks.

Comment: It seems the debugger in ignoring the line "[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];" as I have added it into XMLRPC.xcodeProj(XMLRPC.xcodeProj is open source code)

Comment: But it is working as expected when I run the code in xcode

Comment: The debugger doesn't selectively ignore lines of code. More probably, the program that the debugger is running doesn't have that line of code in it. Please edit your question to explain your build process in full—all of the target dependencies and subprojects that you have going on between your framework project and your application project.